# What is the importance of integral domains?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the importance of integral domains?
In abstract algebra
Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess that you will not be able to find a right answer. There is no reason to be more or less important. You can obtain interesting facts using integral domains or not.

Comment: Sidestepping the subjective question of importance, I think the main *usefulness* of IDness is in left and right cancellation.

Comment: From an algorithmic point of view, cancellation law is a very nice property if you're writing an algorithm to perform some computations. But that's in no way a mathematical motivation of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Definition:**
An Integral domain is a commutative ring( with unity) $(R,+,\cdot)$ for which the following property holds

If $a,b \in R$ such that $a,b \neq 0$, then $ab\neq 0$.

To see some motivation behind the definition of an Integral domain, notice that when we were little kids, while solving polynomial equations in $\mathbb Z$, after factoring a polynomial, we make the jump from

> $$x(x-2)(x-3)=0$$

$$\text{to}$$

> $$x=0 \text{ or } x=2 \text{ or } x=3$$

This is a convenient property to have, since it almost always makes it easy to find ALL solutions of a polynomial equation.And this property holds for all elements if and only if the ring is an integral domain. This is quite easy to verify.

Another motivation is the following question:

> Given a ring $R$, when does there exist a field $F$ and an injective ring homomorphism $\phi:R \to F$?

Informally, we are asking when a given ring $R$ can be described as a subring of a field. The answer turns out that this is possible if and only if $R$ is an integral domain.

One direction of this is easy. Suppose that $R$ can be embedded into a field as above. For any two elements $a,b\neq 0 \in R$, if $ab=0$, then $\phi(ab)=0$ too. Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, this means that $\phi(a)\phi(b)=0$, Since $\phi$ is injective, neither $\phi(a)$ or $\phi(b)$(Both elements of $F$) are zero. Since $F$ is a field, this means they must be invertible. Multiplying on the left by $(\phi(a))^{-1}$, we see that $\phi(b)=0$, a contradiction. So, $ab \neq 0$. So, $R$ is an integral domain.

For the other direction, see [Field of Fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions). This is a construction which not only constructs a field containing our Integral Domain, but also constructs the *smallest* such one. For example, the Field of Fractions of $\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Q$, the field of Rational numbers. This might clarify which the construction is called the field of fractions, since $\mathbb Q$ is what we usual think of as fractions.

Thus, the notion of an abstract *Integral* domain is closely modeled after the *Integers*.

Comment: Moreover, it's a commutative ring, and often assumed to have multiplicative identity.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Dear Cameron, thank you. Please feel free to edit if you see any mistakes. I am a beginner to this material, afterall.:)

Comment: Quite alright. I'm not sure you'd be notified of edits to your post, though, and this way, you also learn something else about the subject. ^_^

Answer (score 4):

@Cameron Buie is correct, if a bit brief.  Integral domains eliminate two "undesirable" properties from a general ring: non-commutativity, and zero divisors.  I think the latter property is more important, because if we eliminate zero divisors, then we gain the *cancellation rule*: if $ca = cb$, then $a = b$.  We can't say this if we have zero divisors: i.e. $a,b$ are zero divisors if $ab=0$ but $a,b\ne0$. Zero divisors occur in non-trivial situations: e.g. matrix rings, modulo integer arithmetic for non-prime modulus, etc.  Integral domains then go on to have other nice properties (e.g. a quotient field), but on an intuitive level, commutativity and cancellation are very nice properties on their own.

Answer (score 3):

It is a very useful abstraction.  It rests on a huge field of examples.  One thing that is interesting is that if $R$ is an i.d., then $R[X]$is an i.d. too.